# Google is merging content from two pages Gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, google-search-console

I'm experiencing a very weird issue with Google indexing and this is reflected in the Google Search Console. The crawled content of the page seems to be a "merge" or a Frenkstein of two different pages. It is like is taking framgemnts of two pages and blend them together in what it crawled. This is finally reflected in the SERP where content is wrong.

Because originally this was messing the canonical too, a lot of focus went on the metatags but there are no issue with canonical, sitempas or any other obvious configuration. On the page there is no reference of the URL or the content the search console is confusing the merging with and of course this issue cannot be replicated on the live version of the page, it is ONLY in Google.

I'm using Gatsby 5 without Helmet but apparently the issue happen regardless Gatsby version (I tried, 2,3,4,5) or Helmet or the new native Head Api. I even completely remove any manipulation of the  and hardcoded the in the metatags required head but I got hte same result.
EVen if the metatags in the head are fine, content from the body can be mismatched

What can be causing Google to "store" a version of teh page which merge two pages without any obvious relationship al all or reference on the page?